# Extra Face when cutting a window

Tags: uv, modifiers, faces

I'm kind of new to Blender and I ran into a problem.  I am creating modular segments for a house.  For some reason when I created the segment with a window in it, blender split the front face into 2 faces when I go into edit mode.  Is there a way to rectify this?  I created the segment using 2 cubes.  One cube is the size of the wall, the other i used to cut out the window using a boolean modifier. I tried the "f" key and that didn't work for me.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Don't use booleans learn proper modelling techniques

Comment: A face by definition can not have a hole inside it.  if you need the hole, there has to be 2 faces.  Trying to merge the 2 faces into 1 will not yield you any viable result.  Instead, I recommend you to get your own lines cut into the faces so the cuts are nicer to look at, and easier to be left alone.

Comment: You way want to check out the archimesh addon for modular house parts.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to subdivide a plane, select, with B, the faces you want to remove or the window and delete them. Then you select the object and extrude it.